# How to use parallel lists of dependencies in makefile?

Tags: makefile

In my project I have a test/ folder.  In this folder each cpp file will be built into a single executable in the Build/test/ folder.

I set up the following variables.

```
BUILD_DIR = Build
TEST_SOURCES = $(wildcard test/*.cpp)
TEST_EXEC = $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/,$(basename $(TEST_SOURCES)))
```

I then created the following rules.

```
$(TEST_EXEC): $(TEST_SOURCES)
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CC) $(INCLUDES) $^ -o $@

test: $(TEST_EXEC)

all: test
```

Right now I have two cpp files in my test directory (test1.cpp and test2.cpp).  This issue is the the test1 target is really only dependent on test1.cpp and not test2.cpp.

```
/usr/local/gcc-7.2/bin/g++-7.2 -I/usr/local/gcc-7.2/include/ -Iinclude/ test/test1.cpp test/test2.cpp -o Build/test/test1
/tmp/ccAQUS3n.o: In function `main':
test2.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `main'
/tmp/ccQ8lewg.o:test1.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
Makefile:10: recipe for target 'Build/test/test1' failed
```

Is there a way to take only the corresponding dependency from $TEST_SOURCES and leave out the others.  I wan't to have...

```
Build/test/test1: test/test1.cpp
Build/test/test2: test/test2.cpp
```

and not

```
Build/test/test1: test/test1.cpp test/test2.cpp
Build/test/test2: test/test1.cpp test/test2.cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use VPATH and implicit rules.

```
BUILD_DIR = Build
TEST_SOURCES = $(wildcard test/*.cpp)
TEST_EXEC = $(basename $(TEST_SOURCES))

VPATH = $(BUILD_DIR):test

all: test

test: $(TEST_EXEC)

%: %.cpp | $(BUILD_DIR)
    echo $(CC) $(INCLUDES) $^ -o $(BUILD_DIR)/$@

$(BUILD_DIR):
    mkdir -p $(@D)
```

So every target depend on its source only (headers dependency should be added somewhere) and the target directory is build only if missing.